# ESTA help please!

Tags: transit, esta, applications, cruising

I am flying to Vancouver and staying in a hotel for three days before boarding a cruise ship to Alaska.  The cruise ends in Anchorage and I fly home via Seattle to Heathrow the same day.   Do I say yes or no to 'in transit' on the ESTA application please?

Answer (score 2):

The "in transit" term usually means that you are taking the same mode of transport in and out. But if you are transferring from a ship to a plane, that's not really transit. So I would suggest "No".

For the purposes of ESTA, it doesn't really matter either way, since you would get the same kind of entry permission (the [Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html)) no matter which way you choose. And if you are a UK citizen, it's unlikely to matter at all. Enjoy your trip!